# HTML align left and align right not working

Tags: html, css

I want to put the image on the left and the other one to right, but it's not working. The image on the left is on top and the image on the right is at the bottom.

Here's my code

```
<tr>
<td valign="top" bgcolor="#f5f2e5" class="promos" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <table  class="headline_1" width="333" align="left">
        <tr>
            <!--HOSTED IMAGE-->
            <td bgcolor="#fff" style="background-image: url('http://ml.nextoptionregistration.com/responsive/nextoption-mailer-01/01_02.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat;" background="http://ml.nextoptionregistration.com/responsive/nextoption-mailer-01/01_02.png" width="333px" height="204" valign="top">
            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            <v:rect style="width:333px;" strokecolor="none">
            <v:fill type="tile" color="#fff" src="http://ml.nextoptionregistration.com/responsive/nextoption-mailer-01/01_02.png" /></v:fill>
            </v:rect>
            <v:shape id="text1" style="position:absolute;width:333px;">
            <![endif]-->
                <p style="font-size:21px;font-family:arial, Helvetian;font-weight:bold;color:#e98106;padding:120px 0px 0px 90px; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                <a href="https://www.nextoption.com/registration" name="read_more" xtlinkname="read_more" xt="SPCLICK" target="_blank" style="color:#e98106;text-decoration:underline;">
                    Click Here To Start >>
                </a>
                </p>
            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            </v:shape>
            <![endif]-->
            </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table  class="headline_2" width="365" align="right">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img alt="" src="01_03.png"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
```

Comment: Have you tried `float:left` and `float:right`

Comment: I would avoid using inline styling for a start...

Comment: Yes, I second the idea of not using inline styling and the other thing I see is you are using tables within table cells and the padding and margin of other elements you are using will increase and decrease the width causing this alignment issue!

Answer (score 0):

you should try float:left and float:right .
and try to increase your code richness use css property
In html5 align maybe not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

The align attribute affects the content of the table, not the table itself.

Also consider not using tables at all, tables shouldn't really be used for layout. Use divs, and css to add float left on the first item.

If you want to keep tables, the items you want beside each other should be in separate cells on the same row.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<tr>
<td valign="top" bgcolor="#f5f2e5" class="promos" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
  
    <table  class="headline_2" width="100%" align="right">
        <tr>
            <td>
                 <img alt="" src="http://ml.nextoptionregistration.com/responsive/nextoption-mailer-01/01_02.png" width="100%"/>                
            </td>
            <td>
                <img alt="" src="http://ml.nextoptionregistration.com/responsive/nextoption-mailer-01/01_02.png" width="100%"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
```

May be it will help you.